# Avoid too many arguments in a method

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid to pass too many arguments to a method, currently I am passing 5, which I consider would make the code harder to maintain and less clean. In this case the method generic_column. 
Currently passes 5 arguments but it might pass 8 or more.

```
class BranchBuilder(object):
    """docstring forBranchBuilder."""
    def __init__(self, raw):
        self.raw = raw

    @staticmethod
    def generic_column(size, posx, distance, raw=True,
                       color="red", complex=True):
        """Build the column according the needed requirements."""
    # creates column with arguments.
        return generic_column

    def builder(self):
        """Build the branch that contains all the columns."""
        initial_column = self.generic_column(3, 120, 66, raw=True,
                                             color="white", complex=False)
        mid_column = self.generic_column(3, 120, 66, raw=False, color="black",
                                         complex=False)
        last_column = self.generic_column(3, 120, 66, raw=False, complex=True)
```

I would like to found a way to make it easier to maintain and clear to any other person who has to deal with the code ahead.

Comment: have you looked in to `*args` and `**kwargs`

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if that could make the code harder to read, as alternative I was thinking to create a class only for the column builder, but I am not sure if that would be too much.

Comment: Read this article https://www.matheus.ro/2018/01/29/clean-code-avoid-many-arguments-functions/. It may help you. If you want to write clean code, you should read this book https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882. For example, you may need to group size, posx, and distance to Column class

Comment: Thank you, it seems that is a great guide, I wish it was written for python to understand faster what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `**kwargs`:

```
def generic_column(**kwargs):
    """Build the column according the needed requirements."""
# creates column with arguments.
    return generic_column
```

Comment: Sure, I am aware of that, my worries is that I have always read that having too many arguments should be avoided, and in this case I wanted to create a generic builder but to make it flexible it needs many arguments.

Comment: @Zabander Edited mine.

Comment: This seems it can work, my only concern if using by using kwargs could be less easy for other user to understand my code, but I guess I can enforce a exception typerror if the keys submitted doesn't match a validation list, and document in the docstring the valid key arguments